# After authorizing one PC for USB debugging, how to restrict all other authorization and disable the authorization popup on Android?

Tags: usb-debugging, authorization

After authorizing one PC for USB debugging, how to restrict all other authorization and disable the authorization popup on Android?

I just don't want to accidentally accept other PCs authorization since I am debugging over network. Thanks.